# Why has my hard disk started dying all of a sudden?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, battery, kubuntu

I have explained the complete environment/set up of my laptop in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767904/how-to-most-efficiently-manage-a-kubuntu-operating-system-along-with-many-softwa). It is long, so I am not repeating it here. *Please note that is a completely separate question and hence this is not a duplication.*

Now, since about a week ago, out of nowhere, while booting, I started getting the following error saying `American Megatrends... S.M.A.R.T. status bad, backup and replace. ...`

[image]

Next I get the following prompt to enter my username and then also asks for password (the oranged-out part is my username)

[image]

And then follows the regular booting. Once I have finally logged into my Kubuntu, I get the following `Storage device likely to fail` notification:

[image]

The following screenshot shows my storage devices:

[image]

**Question:**

1. What could be the cause of this issue to spur up out of nowhere. This hard drive was working just fine. Can it be salvaged without replacing it?
2. This is a HDD. If I absolutely have to replace it, can I replace it with a SSD, for better speed?
3. Is it possible that my hard drive got infected due to a faulty charging adapter? Because a couple of months ago, I had my laptop charger fried or something due to electricity fluctuation and when I took it to the local market to get it repaired, the local vendors kept telling me that a capacitor in the charger adapter was fried and replacing the capacitor would damage my laptop during charging, and so I should buy a Toshiba's not-original-company-made charger from them for my ASUS laptop (because they didn't have an ASUS charger available with them), thus paying them 20 times more price than replacing of capacitor. I made them replace the capacitor, because these local vendors in this market are known for swindling.

Comment: “Is it possible that my hard drive got infected due to a faulty charging adapter?” No. This has nothing to do with the hard drive problem. “This is a HDD. If I absolutely have to replace it, can I replace it with a SSD, for better speed?” Yes it can. Better speed and better reliability.

Comment: `What could be the cause` We do not know. Harddrive go bad after a while for a variety of reasons. Backup, then test your backups then backup your backups.

Comment: "What could be the cause of this issue to spur up out of nowhere." - The drive is failing; it is failing in such a way that it believes it is failing. There is a lot of documentation on how S.M.A.R.T firmware works.  Best if you research that subject yourself. "Can it be salvaged without replacing it?" - It can be salvaged, but you would be ignoring signs that the driver is about to fail.  "Is it possible that my hard drive got infected due to a faulty charging adapter?" - This isn't a thing. What you describe is science fiction.

Comment: The SMART system is telling you, in advance, that the drive is about to fail. Causes can be many: age, power failures or spikes, water damage, falling damage, bad components, etc. If you don't have a backup of your files, DO IT NOW! And yes, you need to buy a new one and replace it. If your computer supports having an SSD, it would be a good opportunity to make the switch. Best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could be the cause of this issue to spur up out of nowhere. This
> hard drive was working just fine.

Due to its mechanical nature, HDDs are always in the process of dying, and when they are working fine, it's just because they haven't died enough yet. Give it time.

> Can it be salvaged without replacing it?

Per the above, you can expect the disk to fail sooner or later. If you have good backups of the contents, then its probably ok to run it into the ground, but if you do not, then it really is past the time you can trust this disk. From what I'm seeing online, this model of Travelstar (hts541010a9e680) was released in 2012.
https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/notebook-hard-drive-review,3270-3.html

> Is it possible that my hard drive got infected due to a faulty
> charging adapter? Because a couple of months ago, I had my laptop
> charger fried or something due to electricity fluctuation and when I
> took it to the local market to get it repaired, the local vendors kept
> telling me that a capacitor in the charger adapter was fried and
> replacing the capacitor would damage my laptop during charging, and so
> I should buy a Toshiba's not-original-company-made charger from them
> for my ASUS laptop (because they didn't have an ASUS charger available
> with them), thus paying them 20 times more price than replacing of
> capacitor. I made them replace the capacitor, because these local
> vendors in this market are known for swindling.

So electronics like mechanical HDDs are certainly susceptible to issues with the supplied electricity. I won't weigh in on anything some repair guy told you, but yes, bad power is a definitely a concern.

Ultimately, I recommend replacing the drive now, while things are easy. if it fails too far, and you don't have up to date backups, the situation becomes far more problematic.